# Why is it not possible for Stern Gerlach to be done in a uniform field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

Why is it not possible to do the stern gerlach experiment in a uniform field?  What makes it non classical?

Answer (score 2):

Because in uniform fields there is no net force on the atoms, regardless of their magnetic dipole moment. The energy of the interaction has the form
$$
U = - \vec \mu\cdot\vec B(\vec r) = -g\,\vec\sigma\cdot\vec B(\vec r);
$$
the force is given by the spatial gradient of the energy (and the torque by its gradient with respect to orientation). Thus, in a uniform field, there is no gradient, no force, and no way to spatially separate the atoms by their magnetic dipole - which is what Stern-Gerlach magnets are meant to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Because there would not be a net force on the atom and so it would not be deflected.
The forces could act as a couple which would produce a rotational motion but no translation motion.

Answer (score 0):

The Stern-Gerlach experiment in its entirety can be seen as a semiclassical: the translational degrees of freedom can be well-approximated by classical motion whereas the internal degree of freedom is quantum. You need a magnetic field gradient to obtain a net deflection of the two spin components as they pass through the magnet for otherwise the potential $U$ Emilio defined above would be constant.

You can find an in-depth explanation of this in Section 5 of [Gat, Lein & Teufel, Annales Henri Poincaré **15**, 1967 (2014)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00023-013-0294-0).